# Any rerefence of CPU world statistics?

Tags: memory, cpu, cpu-speed, statistics, cpu-cores

I am looking for any referencee about computer power statistics across the world.

My main interest is about real computing capabilities, so I'd prefer information about real processor power, and even best if it includes also other critical hardware statistics, like RAM memory, but if it isn't possible, maybe statistics about brand/model distribution will be also useful.

I've Googled for some minutes and I've found nothing related.

Comment: The main problem here is that there is no such list. You will only find what people volentary choose to share (e.g. via bsdstats or by granting steam the rights to scan). Those lists are not quite representative since the measured group is not.

Comment: Of course I count with that, but maybe-not-really-representative and maybe-not-properly-gathered info is best than nothing =)

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could find to what your are looking for is the [Steam Hardware Survey](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey)

Comment: Nice one! Survey was the word I haven't tried! Another simmilar one is the [Unity Hardware statistics](http://stats.unity3d.com/). I'll leave this open for more incoming suggestions, but your answer was great, thank you!